# jQuery check if element have specific attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

I am trying to see if an element have a specific CSS attribute. I am thinking at something like this:

```
if ( !$(this).attr('font-style', 'italic')) {
alert ("yop")
}
else {
alert ("nope")
}
```

It does not work. Any tips on this?
Thank you!

Comment: +1 due to the answer it recieved :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple plugin to do that (tested):

```
$.fn.hasCss = function(prop, val) {
    return $(this).css(prop.toLowerCase()) == val.toLowerCase();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("a").hasCss("Font-Style", "Italic"));
});

<a style="fonT-sTyle:ItAlIc">Test</a>
```

Comment: I do see the merit of this approach :) +1 for that.

Comment: Your code works. I went like this and do a small modification:

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectable1 span').live('click', function() {
$.fn.hasCss = function(prop, val) {
    return $(this).css(prop) == val;
}

 if ($(this).hasCss("font-style", "italic")) {
    alert ("yes")
    }
    else {
    alert ("nop")
    }
                
                 
});
});
</script>

Comment: @Mircea - out of curiosity, I pasted your code change in my edit tool - and wondered if this might be better $(document).ready(function()
{
    $.fn.hasCss = function(prop, val)
    {
        return $(this).css(prop) == val;
    };
    $('#selectable1 span').live('click', function()
    {
        if ($(this).hasCss("font-style", "italic"))
        {
            alert("yes");
        } else
        {
            alert("nop");
        }
    });
}); allows reuse of plug-in outside the live

Comment: @karim79 - would not toLowerCase be better as toUpperCase?

Comment: @Mark - I've tested your code changes and it works fine. Allowing the reuse of the plugin outside the live is a plus. Thanx

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to get a css style. The css method can get the information

```
if ( !$(this).css('font-style') == "italic") {
    alert ("yop")
}
else {
    alert ("nope")
}
```

Comment: Looks good but it does not work on my code. The italic is added dynamically but I am using live and it should work...

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectable1 span').live('click', function() {
if ( !$(this).css('font-style') == "italic") {
    alert ("yop")
}
else {
    alert ("nope")
}                 
                 
});
});
</script>

Answer (score 1):

you can get the font-style element and use == operator to get true/false value:

```
if($(this).attr('font-style') == 'italic')
{
    alert('yes')
}
else
{
    alert('no')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
 if ($(this).css('font-style', 'italic')) {
    alert ("yes")
    }
    else {
    alert ("nop")
    }
```

But I'd rather use console.log instead of alert if I were you, use firebug its less annoying and more fun :D

```
<script>

     $(document).ready(function(){ 
         $('#selectable1 span').live('click', function() { 
            if (!($(this).css("font-style","italic"))){ 
                alert ("yop"); 
              } else { 
                alert ("nope"); 
              } 
         }); 
     }); 

</script>
```

I don't see why this shouldn't work..

Comment: thanx, 
The code looks good but for some reason does not work for me. i am looking into this
indeed the alert noise makes me bleed...

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
if ( $(this).attr('font-style') !=  'italic') {
  alert ("yop")
}
else {
  alert ("nope")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a morf of the conditional and a few semi columns added:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#selectable1 span').live('click', function()
    {
        if ($(this).css('font-style') != "italic")
        {
            alert("yop");
        } 
        else
        {
            alert("nope");
        };
    });
});
```

NOTE: Making assumption regarding the select and subsequent markup based on other comments - would need to see the html to make sure on that.