# How to add a class if style attribute is present using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I referred to this page, but I must be doing something wrong: [jQuery check if element have specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333802/jquery-check-if-element-have-specific-attribute)

Basically, I want to add a class of "img-left" if an image has style="float: left" attribute, and "img-right" if style="float: right;" My HTML looks like this:

```
<img class="content-img" style="float: left;" src="/images/my-img.jpg">
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
<img class="content-img img-left" style="float: left;" src="/images/my-img.jpg">
```

This is what I've tried:

```
if ($('.content-img').css('float' == 'left')) {
    $(this).addClass('img-left');
}
else {
    $(this).addClass('img-right');
}
```

This produces a JS error but I cannot sort out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Vaughn

Comment: +1 for "This is what I've tried", I've seen too many "Give me teh codez" posts recently, that this makes me happier than it probably should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest simplifying this to the following:

```
$('.content-img').addClass(
    function(){
        var floated = $(this).css('float');
        return floated ? 'img-' + floated : '';
    });
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K8gLa/).

This retrieves the `float` property and, if it's set (having a truthy value), returns the string `img-` concatenated with the value of the `floated` variable.

Answer (score 3):

That's right, but there's a typo in the `if` condition.  Should be like this:

```
if ($('.content-img').css('float') == 'left') {
    $('.content-img').addClass('img-left');
}
```

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem to be working. I have it here, but no luck: http://www.receivablesxchange.com/smb-receivables/the-exchange-solution/ - it's the bag of cash image.

Comment: @VaughnD.Taylor I see what the problem is -- you have $(this).addClass, which will attempt (unsuccessfully) to add the class to the *document* object.  Please see my updated answer.