# detect bold and italic support

Tags: javascript, css

Some fonts do not support CSS italic or bold (e.g. [Zapfino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapfino) does not support italic, as it is already pretty scripty-looking).  I want to detect when a font style is not supported so I can disable styling buttons in an editor.

I tried something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript/118251#118251):

```
that.checkFontData = function( fontList )
{   var test = $("<span style='font-size:24px;absolute;visibility:hidden;height:auto;width:auto;white-space:nowrap;'>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678910</span>");
    $('body').append( test );
    for (var i= 0, iMax = fontList.length; i < iMax; ++i)
    {   test.css( 'fontFamily', fontList[i] );
        var normalWidth = test.outerWidth( true );
        var normalHeight = test.outerHeight( true );
        test.css( 'fontStyle', 'italic' );
        var italicWidth = test.outerWidth( true );
        var italicHeight = test.outerHeight( true );
        test.css( 'fontStyle', 'normal' );
        test.css( 'fontWeight', 'bold' );
        var boldWidth = test.outerWidth( true );
        var boldHeight = test.outerHeight( true );
        console.log( fontList[i]  + ", normal: " + normalWidth + ", bold: " + boldWidth + ", italic: " + italicWidth  );
    }
    test.remove( );
};
```

but it does not work... many fonts which provide italic or bold report the same widths.

Next, I thought to detect this with a canvas element, but, alas, firefox does not even render italic text in the canvas, so that botches that idea.

What would you suggest?

Comment: OCR, if really important. cant come up with anything better

Comment: check it manually, and hardcode your results

Comment: having hard coded results like P1nGu1n suggest would be the best most logical solution in my mind. Presumably you control your own fonts - this should be easy.

Comment: i should see this following link

[test ccs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2333865/1926761

Answer (score 4):

To detect **bold** and *italic* support, you can convert text into image and compare them.

The way to do it is:

1. create a `canvas`<sup>See below</sup> (no need to append it to the DOM)
2. draw text in the `canvas`
3. convert the canvas into an image (here I use `png`)
4. compare the base64 string of the image

Regarding `canvas`:

> Next, I thought to detect this with a canvas element, but, alas, firefox does not even render italic text in the canvas, so that botches that idea.

Certain fonts are not italicize in a canvas in Firefox because the native italic font does not exist. Other browsers would try to psuedo-italicize (tilt) the font.

**[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4gfq/3/)** (this demo also tests for the Google font `Snowburst One`)

```javascript
function detectBoldItalic(fonts) {
    // Create canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 30;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var test = {}, results = {};
    // Default
    context.font = "normal 16px a base case font";
    context.fillText("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678910", 10, 20);
    var standard = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // Start test
    for (var i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
        var styles = ["normal", "bold", "italic"];
        test[fonts[i]] = {};
        results[fonts[i]] = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < styles.length; j++) {
            // Draw text in canvas
            context.font = styles[j] + " 16px " + fonts[i];
            context.fillText("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678910", 10, 20);
            // Convert canvas to png
            test[fonts[i]][styles[j]] = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            // Clear canvas
            context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        if (test[fonts[i]]["normal"] !== standard) {
            results[fonts[i]]["bold"] = test[fonts[i]]["normal"] !== test[fonts[i]]["bold"] ? true:false; // Support bold
            results[fonts[i]]["italic"] = test[fonts[i]]["normal"] !== test[fonts[i]]["italic"] ? true:false; // Support italic
        } else {
            results[fonts[i]] = false; // Font does not exist
        }
    }
    return results;
}
console.log(detectBoldItalic(["Arial","Zapfino"]));
```

Comment: I believe there is no way to specify `font-stretch: condensed` on a canvas element. So I believe there is no way to detect the support for italic/bold `Arial Narrow` font using your method. Your answer is still the best though on other merits - specifically because it is able to differentiate more precisely different fonts styles.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code in jsFiddle, and it does give different sizes for natural webfonts like  `Georgia` and `Arial`, but not for an externally loaded font like  `Snowburst One` (Googlefont).

[JS fiddle of your script](http://jsfiddle.net/v6b9Q/1/)

After some research I've found out that for `@font-face` loaded fonts no css font-transformations apply. People load the `@font-face` variations and apply them like so:

```
body { font-family:"DroidSerifRegular", Georgia, serif; }
h1 {
    font-family:"DroidSerifBold", Georgia, serif;
    font-weight:normal;
}
em {
    font-family:"DroidSerifItalic", Georgia, serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
strong em {
    font-family:"DroidSerifBoldItalic", Georgia, serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

If you are using `@font-face` fonts that have variations like in the example above, you might be able to come up with some sort of naming convention. Then you can check if these fonts exist by checking the width compared to the fallback font.

```
test.css('fontFamily', 'sans-serif');
var defaultWidth = test.outerWidth( true );

for (var i= 0, iMax = fontList.length; i < iMax; ++i)
{   test.css( 'fontFamily', fontList[i] + ', sans-serif' );

    var normalWidth = test.outerWidth( true );
    var normalHeight = test.outerHeight( true );
    test.css( 'fontFamily', fontList[i] + 'Italic, sans-serif' );
    var italicWidth = test.outerWidth( true );
    var italicHeight = test.outerHeight( true );
    test.css( 'fontFamily', fontList[i] + 'Bold, sans-serif' );
    var boldWidth = test.outerWidth( true );
    var boldHeight = test.outerHeight( true );
    console.log( "default: "+ defaultWidth + ", " fontList[i]  + ", normal: " + normalWidth + ", bold: " + boldWidth + ", italic: " + italicWidth  );
}
```

If the styled versions have an altered width compared to the default, then it's a "Bingo"!

Note: this won't work for monospace fonts, as the width of all characters is always the same.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, you only test Georgia, never Arial. Try replacing the first line with `var fontlist = ["Georgia", "Arial"];` and you will see that Arial gets the same dimensions in normal and italic.

Comment: I fixed the issue with the array. The same dimensions are caused because the styles are not cleared when the new item of the array is loaded. I've updated my example to fix this.

Comment: Ah, I see where I was confused. Your method for Arial gives different sizes according to different browser/OS combinations. Windows Firefox and Chrome report different dimensions for Arial Italic but IE along with all browsers on Linux gives back the same dimensions for Arial Italic and Arial. So, it is a bit hit and miss...

Answer (score 0):

Using Font.js you might have more reliable access to font metrics for your calculation. http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/pages/Font.js